# Небольшие правки на странице описания привилегии по доступу к аналитике

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, привилегии

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

1. > Дополнительные права на Stack Overflow на русском выдаются за повышение репутации в результате участия в жизни веб-сайта. Когда Вы заработаете по крайней мере 25000 очков репутации, Вы получите право «доступ к статистике сайта» и сможете просмотреть эту страницу.

   1. У нас вроде договорённость **Вы** в таких текстах с маленькой буквы писать.
   2. **по крайней мере** выделяется запятыми?
2. > Для посещения страницы необходимы расширенные права “доступ к статистике сайта.”

Тут косяк, что у нас, что в en версии https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics.
Точка должна быть вне кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

1. https://ru.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
2. Есть такое: https://ru.traducir.win/string/4771. И такое: https://ru.traducir.win/string/9899

   Но поправить через интерфейс никак. Видимо, хардкод какой-то.

**UPD:** задал [вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336737/260198), чтоб дали возможность поправить перевод.